# Busca de string no banco de dados utilizando linq C# wpf

Tags: c#, query, linq, wpf

Tenho um banco e quero executar uma busca no campo nome, porem também quero que o cliente possa buscar por partes da string ou até mesmo por com letras maiúsculas e minusculas. até o momento minha busca funciona porem a string tem que estar exatamente como esta no banco.

```
using(ConsultorioContext ctx = new ConsultorioContext())
 {
     List<Produto> lista = ctx.Produtos.Where(p => p.Id == id || p.Nome == nome).ToList();
     return lista;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `Contains`, ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
using(ConsultorioContext ctx = new ConsultorioContext())
 {
     List<Produto> lista = ctx.Produtos.Where(p => p.Id == id || p.Nome.Contains(nome)).ToList();
     return lista;
 }
```

Ele é como se fosse um `like` do SQL.

Comment: Funciono perfeitamente, muito obrigado